# How can I override configuration in logback-spring.xml with properties in Spring's own application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-logback, apache-commons-logging

In my Spring Boot project, I initially set up the logging configuration in the application.properties, e.g.

```
logging.file=/foo/bar/app.log
logging.file.max-size=1M
logging.file.max-history=10
logging.file.level.root=DEBUG
logging.file.level.root.com.my.app=DEBUG
logging.file.level.org.springframework.boot.diagnostics=DEBUG
logging.file.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

Let's say I have other environment-specific properties files named following this pattern `application-xxx.properties` with `xxx` being the Spring profile name passed as argument when running the app (via `-Dspring.profiles.active=xxx`).

In these files, I can override the log levels, e.g. for an `application-qa.properties`

```
logging.file.level.root=INFO
logging.file.level.root.com.my.app=INFO
logging.file.level.org.springframework.boot.diagnostics=INFO
logging.file.level.org.springframework.security=INFO
```

I can also override these in the command line with the same mechanism as explained above (`-D` ).

Now, I'm asked to transfer all this configuration into a single `logback-spring.xml`. Using this new style of configuration, is there a way to still **override** each properties?

Found these resources while looking for an answer:

- neither official Spring doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging
- nor this DZone article mention that: https://dzone.com/articles/configuring-logback-with-spring-boot
- this article on CodeJava: https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/logback-rolling-files-example even says it works the other way round: *The configuration in XML file will override the logging properties in the application.properties file.* !!!

Comment: have you looked into this?

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging.logback-extensions.profile-specific

Comment: @bananas I have. But my question remains the same: is there a way to still override these properties?

Comment: @maxxyme did you found solution for your problem?

Comment: @fascynacja unfortunately not, and I quit this company/project so I can’t tell you if they ended up solving this or not. Too bad!